# How to check if a substring is at the end of a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String

```
String str = "Hello there how are you"
```

and a substring

```
String substr = "how are you".
```

I am checking if the string contains the substring like this:

```
if (str.toLowerCase().contains(substr.toLowerCase())) {
    // now check if substr is the last part of str
}
```

If the substring *is* within the string, I want to check whether or not the substring is the last part of the string. Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `indexOf` method and apply some basic arithmetic.

Comment: you can rather use endsWith directly http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: When in doubt, read the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be wanting the [`String.endsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) method:

```
if (str.toLowerCase().endsWith(substr.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about endsWith()! Thanks for the help, will accept in 7 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`endsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method instead of a multi-step approach, if that's all you want to know:

```
if (str.toLowerCase().endsWith(substr.toLowerCase())) {
```

If you need to know both (because you have content outside the second `if` below), and/or do something else more advanced, you can use separate lines:

```
if (str.toLowerCase().contains(substr.toLowerCase())) {
    if (str.toLowerCase().endsWith(substr.toLowerCase())) {
    }
}
```